# QGIS Vector Data with blank attribute tables

Tags: qgis, shapefile, vector, labeling, canada

I have vector data shapefiles for Manitoba, but there is no names in the attribute tables. It seems Manitoba is still working on their attribute data. Is there a shapefile I can download to get these labels? How can I get labels for all these features? Please Help.

Edit: Just the basic topographic features like the names associated with lakes, rivers, towns, etc. I know how to turn on labels from existing data, but i'm unsure how to label features that do not have the names in the attribute tables

Comment: Please include some details about what you are looking for. Label which features? Can you share the Shapefiles you have for testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download a Canada shapefile from [DIVA-GIS](http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata) and selecting the *Administrative areas* as the subject. You will receive 4 shapefiles of differing levels:

- Can_adm0
- Can_adm1
- Can_adm2
- Can_adm3 *(this is probably the one you want)*

When loaded into QGIS, you will see Canada broken up into different districts (or wards, zones, etc.). You can run a query to only show Manitoba by selecting from the toolbar: *Layer > Query...*

Then enter the following:

```
"NAME_1"  LIKE  'Manitoba'
```

[image: Layer query]

[image: Attribute table]

You can then label this layer using the column `"Name_3"` which will give you the names of the features inside the attribute table:

[image: Manitoba]

And here's Manitoba with the Google Hybrid layer from OpenLayers plugin:

[image: Manitoba with Google Hybrid]

Hope this helps!

*Note that this shapefile may not contain the data you are looking as it probably won't be as detailed as one created by the officials of Manitoba.*

Comment: Thanks for the tips! It works fairly well. Labels are a bit askew but I think that should be fixable. Side Question: Is there a way to query for multiple strings?

Comment: @ChrisProtulipac - Most welcome buddy! Hopefully you'll be able to play around with the labels and get them the way you want :). To answer your side question: Yes, you can use the `IN` function followed by your list of strings all inside brackets. E.g. `"NAME_1" IN ('Alberta', 'British Columbia', 'Manitoba')`.